# Dynamically (server side) adding and removing columns in ag-grid with GraphQL(Apollo), React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have the following issue:

I am using GraphQL to query data from a huge table with many columns. The users want to be able to add/remove columns based on their preferences. I know that ag-grid offers adding/removing columns, but only client side (all columns are loaded). Because of the table size, this is not possible. I am trying to dynamically build a list of fields that I need, add them to a GraphQL query and run the query again. (again, because it runs once on page load.)

Here is an example of the query:

```
  query headers{
    getHeaders{
      headerId
      name
      description
      date
    }
  }
```

this is how I am currently doing the call:

```
const GET_HEADERS = gql`
    query headers {
        getHeaders {
            ${headerFields.join('\n')}
        }
    }
`;

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_HEADERS);
setRowData(data.getHeaders);
```

`headerFields` gets updated, but how do I ask Apollo to take the new query string and execute it again?

I've seen few people saying that dynamic queues are not a good practice, but in this case I see no other solution. I've tried using  `refetch()` but it doesn't change the query fields. It basically updates the cache.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this is using directive:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/directives/

```
const GET_HEADERS = gql`
  query headers(
    $headerId: Boolean!
    $name: Boolean!
    $description: Boolean!
    $date: Boolean!
  ) {
    getHeaders {
      headerId @include(if: $headerId)
      name @include(if: $name)
      description @include(if: $description)
      date @include(if: $date)
    }
  }
`;

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_HEADERS, {
  variables: {
    headerId: false,
    name: true,
    description: false,
    date: true,
  },
});
```

now I can set the variables to true and false like this:

```
const setAttributes = (attributes) => {
    if (Array.isArray(attributes)) {
        const updatedState = {};
        Object.keys(state).forEach((key) => {
            updatedState[key] = attributes.includes(key);
        });
        setState(updatedState);
    } else {
        console.error('Invalid attributes. Please provide an array.');
    }
};
```

Here is the neat part, when I setState, which basically updates my state hook which looks like this:

```
state = {headerId: false,
        name: true,
        description: false,
        date: true}
```

it automatically does another graphql request.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that comes to mind is to use components.

1. ComponentA - has the controls that allow the user to pick which fields s/he wants, saving that list as *state*. This Component would build the query as a *prop* that it would use to call
2. ComponentB - this would execute the query passed in via prop using `useQuery` and render the results.

That way whenever the user changed the *state* of ComponentA by editing the field list, ComponentB would be forced to rerun the query and rerender.